# Play for Scala: replicate structure in Json of array within array

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

I have in Scala an array `array1` that contains, among other things, another array `array2`.

Now, I'm trying to replicate the structure in Json using Play. This is my attempt:

```
    var json = JsObject(Seq())
    array1.foreach(a1 => {
      json += "a1" -> JsNumber(a1.name) + 
      "a2" -> a1.array2.foreach {
        a2 => "a2" -> JsString(a2.name)
      }
    })
```

The error I'm getting is `type mismatch; found : Unit required: play.api.libs.json.JsValue`

How to fix this? thanks in advance.

Comment: Use `map` instead of `foreach`. `foreach` is for side-effect operations

Comment: Could you provide an example of how do your arrays look like? It would be easier to reproduce your error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want is to use map instead of foreach in the loops.

It's a little unclear as to what json you want, but based on the description of your objects, I'd say this is probably what you are a looking for:

```
val json =  JsArray(array1.map { a1 =>
  JsObject(List(
    "a1" -> JsNumber(a1.name),
    "a2" -> JsArray(a1.array2.map {
      a2 => JsString(a2.name)
    })
  ))
})
```